# Does the brain always enter alpha/beta waves upon brief awakenings during the night?

Tags: neuroscience, sleep, psychology

If you realize you are awake briefly before falling back asleep, have you *necessarily* exited REM sleep or another stage? That is, is the experience of waking briefly (tossing and turning, etc.) always tied to conscious beta wave patterns?